# Setting multiple selection in QTreeView

Tags: qt

I have a need here regarding multiple selection of items in the `QTreeView`. I have two widgets, `QTreeView` on left and another `QGLWidget` on the right. If I do a multiple selection, I must highlight the items in the glwidget. Vice versa, I need to highlight the items in the tree view if multiple selection is done on the glwidget. Currently, I am able to update single item by setting the current index of the tree view. Any ideas on how to update the selection of multiple items on the tree view with multiple selection on glwidget?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the tree view's item selection model (treeView->selectionMode(), of type QItemSelectionModel). It has a signal selectionChanged() you can connect to to receive tree view selection changes and apply them to the GL view.
When receiving selection events from the GL view, you can use `QItemSelectionModel::select()` to propagate them to the tree view.

To enable multiselection on your treeview, call `setSelectionMode( MultiSelection )`.

Answer (score 7):

Frank was faster, but I still post my (untested) code example for adding an item to the current selection:

```
treeView->selectionModel()->select(
    treeView->model()->index(row, column, parent), 
    QItemSelectionModel::SelectCurrent);
```

There are other selection modes too, see the `QItemSelectionModel` reference. `SelectCurrent` is a short-hand for `Select | Current`, so means update current selection by selecting the given items. It does not mean "select as current selection" (replacing previous selection).

Answer (score 1):

In Python (PyQt6) I do :

```
ui.my_treeView.setSelectionMode(ui.my_treeView.selectionMode().MultiSelection)
```

It works well.